# two dimensional vector vs two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am working on an interview question on leetcode. 
[Longest Palindromic Substring](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/)
In this question, it reaches memory limit when I use two dimensional vector.
But it pass the test when i change it to two dimensional array.

It seems like 2-d vector takes more memory than 2-d array does. Why? 
I will be really appropriate if someone could explain to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To speed up insertion `std::vector<T>` allocate more memory (usually up to 2 times) than it needs so it doesn't have to reallocate every time an element is added. This **greatly** speed up insertion but potentially double the memory consumption.

`std::vector<T>.capacity()` will give you the total capacity of the vector (ie : the number of preallocated element which is the maximum size it can have before having to allocate more memory)
Also `std::vector<T>.shrink_to_fit()` will set the vector capacity to its **current** size, reducing the memory consumption but also making the next insertion slower.

Comment: You can set the vector capacity by passing it to the constructor when initializing it : `std::vector<T> vec(42); // vector with 42 preallocated elements`